# reading from a text files using getline

Tags: c++, c++14

Lets say we have a text file that contains the rows and columns in the first line and the name and grades on the preceding lines. How can we read the first line, get the info from it, and read the preceding lines in a loop, and pass into a pointer arrays. I was trying to do something like the below code, but it keeps printing out nothing.

```
while (inputFile.good()) {
        getline(inputFile, accessInputFilesInfo);
        istringstream accessFiles(accessInputFilesInfo);
        accessFiles >> rows >> cols;
          while (getline(inputFile, accessInputFilesInfo)) {
            accessFiles >> firstName >> lastName;
            studentName = firstName + " " + lastName;
            arrayOfStudentNames[i] = studentName;
            i++;
```

Comment: It would help if you posted a sample of the input file, because from your example I don't see where the grades come into play.

Comment: The file is good here: `while (inputFile.good())`, but you have no guarantees that the file is still good after `getline(inputFile, accessInputFilesInfo);`. You could wind up loading garbage into `accessFiles`.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need another input stream if you're talking about the same input file. If the first line contains the row and column numbers, and the remaining lines contain first and last names of students, you should be able to do something like this.

```
std::ifstream inputFile("somefile.txt");
if (inputFile.is_open())
{
    int rows, cols;
    inputFile >> rows >> cols;
    inputFile.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    std::string studentName;
    while (std::getline(inputFile, studentName))
    {
        // process student name if needed and
        // place result in arrayOfStudentNames
    }
    inputFile.close();
}
```